# Keycloak: Assign group on first login of user that uses an idp

Tags: keycloak

I am using Keycloak 12.

Some of our users will login through IDP (in my tests I use oidc).
I want to assign a specific **group** (not role) to the users that login through the specific IDP.

So each configured IDP should have it's own group. Is this possible? And how ;-)
I don't see any mappers on the IDP that relate to group(s).